# Search for pattern and print them above certain pattern everytime

Tags: awk, sed

If data i have is in below format

```
cell D
type seq
Cd
Input
Cp
Input
Q
Output
Func IQ
Sdn
Input
cell 23
----
```

I want output as I.e in cell , input, output,function , type format.

```
cell D
Cd
Input
Cp
Input
Sdn
Input
Q
Output
Func IQ 
type seq
cell 23
---
```

I.e `Func and type` should come everytime before cell i.e at last.
I dont have any logic how to do it.
In the above output I want when ever there is type and funct in input I want it to be printed at last above cell line. --- for cell 23 represents data for this cell same as cell D format.

Comment: Could you please explain the logic of getting expected output more clearly since its not clear in your question as of now, kindly do add description in your question only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on shown samples only written in GNU `awk`. This is considering that `cell` is coming each time in blocks and if `cell` is not coming in very last occurrence in Input_file then those values will not be printed(you could print them in `END` block then in case you need those values too, left as an exercise for OP).

```
awk '
/^cell/{
  if(funcVal){
    print funcVal
  }
  if(typeVal){
    print typeVal
  }
  funcVal=typeVal=""
}
/^Func/{
  funcVal=(funcVal?funcVal ORS:"")$0
  next
}
/^type/{
  typeVal=(typeVal?typeVal ORS:"")$0
  next
}
1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
/^cell/{                                ##Checking if a line starts from cell then do following.
  if(funcVal){                          ##Checking if funcVal is NOT NULL then do following.
    print funcVal                       ##printing funcVal here.
  }
  if(typeVal){                          ##Checking if typeVal is NOT NULL then do following.
    print typeVal                       ##Printing typeVal value here.
  }
  funcVal=typeVal=""                    ##Nullifying values here.
}
/^Func/{                                ##Checking if line starts from Func then do following.
  funcVal=(funcVal?funcVal ORS:"")$0    ##Creating funcVal and keep adding value of current line to it.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^type/{                                ##Checking if line starts from type then do following.
  typeVal=(typeVal?typeVal ORS:"")$0    ##Creating typeVal and keep adding value of current line to it.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                                       ##Mentioning 1 will print current line.
' Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```